# Android 500 error on image uploading

Tags: java, android, multipartform-data

I am getting 500 server error using multipart. Same server code is working while uploading image from iOS side. Following is my code for multipart image uploading.Server Side is using PHP.

```
public PostFile(String requestURL)
throws IOException {
    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty(
        "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + this.boundary);

    request = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
}
private void saveFile() {
    try {
        PostFile postFile = new PostFile(URL);
        //postFile.addFormField();
        postFile.addFormField("userId", "25");
        postFile.addFormField("accessToken", "h7lCesyM3XKjmjvjrdojzypUNPqA9MsB8PQIzZyWkYHtV43XcxPubUJ3EV8L");
        // contact.accumulate("files",imgData);
        postFile.addFormField("area", "dfs");
        postFile.addFilePart("test.jpeg", getFileFromBitmap(uri));
        postFile.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
throws IOException {
    String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    request.writeBytes(this.twoHyphens + this.boundary + this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
        fieldName + "\";filename=\"" +
        fileName + "\"" + this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes("Content-Type:  image/jpeg;" + this.crlf);
    request.writeBytes(this.crlf);

    // byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(uploadFile.toPath());

    request.write(getBytesFromFile(uploadFile));
}
```

Comment: can you make an attempt to post the php code too ?

Comment: did you set mimetype in your php side?

Comment: @Vikrant I don't have php code with me. Just want to be sure that server code is working with iOS but not with Android.

Comment: @JaiminThakkar yes

Comment: Could you check the file size which you are uploading. And  how much of size of files your PHP code will accept? Is there any limit? Try with other files which are having less size.

Comment: @RaviMCA I am testing with single file and size of file is 25KB Still getting error.

Comment: Could you post the error response here? The error response is supposed to have the cause why File not have been uploaded.

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: `getFileFromBitmap(uri));`. Much to complicated cide. Ahundred thingsgan go wrong. Do you know what all happens? Step by step? Youbetterdo all step by step first and check before you call saveFile().

Comment: You need to set mimetype form android side..@AshwiniPandarkar